# Javascript left key released

Tags: javascript, web

I have some code that when a canvas is clicked, it sends the key event to a function and then uses:

```
if (e.buttons==1) { //code  here }
```

This detects if the left button has been clicked. How would i detect if the left button has been released?

Comment: you can use event listener `mouseup`

Answer (score 0):

To detect a mouse button release, use the [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) event.

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
  //this code will run when the mouse button is released
});
```

For this, I would recommend using window as the user could easily release the button outside of your canvas.